# elasticsearch script query with exists/missing filter

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to run a script with query filter.
the script should return me all books with title gt 30:

```
GET books/_search
{
    "filter" : {       
          "script" : {
              "script" : "_source.title?.length() > 30"
          }
      }
}
```

this works.

but if i try to add some filter, like i want all the books that not has 'type' field :

```
GET book/_search
{
    "filter" : {        
          "script" : {
              "script" : "_source.title?.length() > 30"
          },
          "missing" : { "field" : "type" },
      }
}
```

then i get error:

```
nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"exists\"]; }]
```

so i can i query for missing fields with script filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, you simply need to combine both of your filters into a [`bool/must` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
POST book/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "_source.title?.length() > 30"
          }
        },
        {
          "missing": {
            "field": "type"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: bool/must is just one example, there are more "Compound query clauses": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl.html

Comment: Yes, eventually `dis_max`, indeed.